# Javascript - onsubmit for dynamically created forms not executing function

Tags: javascript, onsubmit

I have a button that on clicking generates a new form with multiple input boxes (with dynamically generated IDs for each element as well). Each form has a submit button. The form when submitted executes a function.

```
<form id='f1' name='form1' onsubmit='return myFunction("1");'>
```

This is a default form that's already present in the page and it works fine.

For the dynamically added form, I set the attribute for onsubmit like:

```
var f = document.createElement("form");
var fn = "f"+number_inserted_dynamically;
var funname = "return myFunction(\""number_inserted_dynamically"\");";
f.setAttribute('onsubmit',funname);
```

This is what I found when I inspected the element on Chrome (for the generated form):

```
<form id="f2" onsubmit="return myFunction("2");">
```

But the function isn't getting executed.

As seen in one of the other questions, I tried using

`f.onsubmit = myFunction;` (with number_inserted_dynamically defined inside myFunction)

which didn't work either.

What's going wrong? How else do I set onsubmit dynamically for the function?

Answer (score 2):

`<form id="f2" onsubmit="return myFunction("2");">` is a syntax error due to the quotes. Your `onsubmit` will evaluate to `return myFunction(` and then throw a syntax error.

Instead of:

```
var funname = "return myFunction(\""number_inserted_dynamically"\");";
```

You'll want:

```
var funname = "return myFunction('number_inserted_dynamically');";
```

So that you end up with:

```
<form id="f2" onsubmit="return myFunction('2');">
```

However, you really should make use of [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), and instead use an event listener:

```
f.addEventListener("submit", return myFunction('2'));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I tried changing the double quotes to single, but the same thing happens. I did this: `var funname="return myFunction('"+elno+"');";`. `addEventListener` didn't work either. The form disappears on clicking the submit button in both cases.

Comment: Btw, when I tried `addEventListener`, no form was created. Clicking the button to add form did nothing.

Answer (score 1):

If jQuery:

```
var eleForm = $('<form>...</form>');

$('body').append(eleForm); // append the form to body

eleForm.on('submit', function() {
   // here to put your code about submitting form
});
```